# PowerShell Script Loop Through Each File And Do A Find And Replace

Tags: powershell

My Current Code Is

```
Param(
  [string]$filePath = "C:\",
  [string]$logFileFind = "error.log",
  [string]$logFileReplace ="ThisHasBeenReplaced.log" 
)


($configFile = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force $filePath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object { ($_.PSIsContainer -eq $false) -and  ( $_.Name -like "*.config") }
```

It Works fine and gives me list of files i was wondering how i could go through these files and find and replace certain words for when I'm moving though environments and the path wont be the same. I'm very limited in my powershell knowledge and i tried adding this to the end of the script.

```
ForEach-Object{(Get-Content $configFile) -replace $logFileFind , $logFileReplace | Set-Content $configFile})
```

This didn't work and i was wondering if there was anyone out there who knew what i could do to make it work.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Try to set the -raw parameter on the Get-Content invoke

Comment: its Saying its invalid data in the Get-Content

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you running in your environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always access `$configFile` in your foreach loop (which is probably an `System.Array`), not the actual element. Try this:

```
$configFile | foreach { (get-content $_.FullName -Raw) -replace $logFileFind , $logFileReplace | Set-Content $_.FullName }
```

Here is a full example:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -force $filePath -ea 0 |
 where { ($_.PSIsContainer -eq $false) -and ( $_.Name -like "*.config") } | 
 foreach { 
   (gc $_.FullName -raw) -replace $logFileFind , $logFileReplace | sc $_.FullName 
 }
```

Comment: It's Throwing up the error Get-Content : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Raw'.

Comment: I updated my answer. Please try again. You could also try to omit the -Raw parameter since the error was the access of your file path.

Comment: The Error message is Get-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.  does this mean there is something wrong with my $configFile?

Comment: Hm, try to print all paths using "$configFile | select -expand FullName"

Comment: It is giving me the FullName when i add it to the Select-Object in my original code

Comment: I upgraded my answer with a full example which works for me.

Comment: Thank you It worked for me just for some reason without the raw only!?